# Xamarin how to open another layout by clicking on new resource layout

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new with Xamarin, but I am training by creating parking application. Now I got issue by trying to access to another layout.

This is my MainActivity.cs

```
    [Activity(Label = "CustomActionBarParking", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme ="@style/CustomActionBarTheme")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
    private LinearLayout mBarZone;
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.action_bar);
                mBarZone = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout2);
                mBarZone.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
                {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.zones_list);
                };
  }}}
```

Here I am accessing from my menu, by clicking on "Zones" action bar. And open "zones list" layout.

From here I want to access to another Layout: vehicle_not_parked by clicking on blue zone action bar button. But I don't know where I have to initialize it, because when I initialized that in MainAcitivy class on OnCreate method, then I got error, that my object is nullable. Then I create ZonesActivity.cs which looks like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "CustomActionBarParking")]
    public class ZonesActivity : Activity
    {
        private LinearLayout mBlueZone;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.zones_list);
            mBlueZone = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout2);
            mBlueZone.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.vehicle_not_parked);

            };

        }}}
```

But when I tryed to call this class in Main Activity class I have to deal with Bundle savedInstanceState property. I am not really know how I can from one view -> 2nd view and then -> 3rd view.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your swapping out the layouts in the button click event? I think it would be best to start a new activity

```
mBarZone.Click += delegate {
       StartActivity(typeof(ZonesActivity));
};
```

[Docs on starting a new activity](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/)

Comment: yes I do swapping. Where I have to start that activity? At MainActitivy class in OnCreate() method? Because When I initialized this activity I got error when I tapped on Layout action bar to get vehicle_not_parked view. : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Have a look at this sample app https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/hello,android_multiscreen_quickstart/ and how the app starts the call history activity https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/PhonewordMultiscreen/Phoneword/MainActivity.cs#L50

Comment: Either that or take a look at this https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/PhonewordMultiscreen/Phoneword/MainActivity.cs#L50 it uses an actionbar and fragments